# Form submission from js only sends the first item from a dynamically generated list with php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to update the quantity of an item automatically when changing the value of an input. I use the "change" function of js and it only recognizes the first line of the items that I have dynamically generated by php.
I send the code and I'm grateful to anyone who can help me.

```
<form id='form3' name='form3' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' id='id_empresa' name='id_empresa' value='$id_empresa' style='display:none;' />
            <input type='text' id='id_cart' name='id_cart' value='$id_cart' style='display:none;' />
            <input type='number' id='cant' name='cant' value='$cant' onClick='this.select();' />
            </form>


<script>
      $('#cant').change(function() { 
              //Obtenemos datos formulario.
              var data = $('#form3').serialize(); 

              //AJAX.
              $.ajax({  
                 type : 'POST',
                 url  : 'sistema/atualiza_cant.php',
                 data:  data, 
                 success:function(data) { 

                 }  
              });
              return false;

      });//Fin document.
    </script>
```

The list can have "n" items and all generated dynamically by PHP, I would like that when modifying the quantity, it automatically updates the value.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the first line of the items"?  I see exactly three `<input>` elements in this `<form>`.  They should serialize to three values and post to the server.  Is that not working in some way?  What specifically is failing?

Comment: Are you saying your page has multiple forms like the one you've shown?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You appear to be generating duplicate IDs which is why your `change` function only works with one form - remove the IDs completely and use better element selection methods within the `change` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment I made above, if you are dynamically generating HTML forms & elements you either need to ensure that the element IDs are all unique or remove them completely and use a more reliable method of identifying form elements.

The `event` ( ie: the `change` event ) allows access to certain properties of the invoking HTML element and `target` and `currentTarget` are particularly useful in trying to determine a source for the event. The following uses a `delegated event handler` that is bound to the document itself and analyses the `event.target` to determine if the event was triggered by one of the number input elements originally identified with id `#cant`

From that event we find the parent form and use that to construct a `FormData` object ( I don't use jQuery so my efforts with jQuery would be misleading perhaps ) and thus issue the AJAX request using `fetch`

This should handle any number of duplicated Forms - though it would be better to remove the IDs I believe it should still work as intended if you do not. It is a much simpler method of identifying elements than trying to use an ID!

```js
document.body.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.hasAttribute('name') && e.target.name=='cant' ){
    let fd=new FormData( e.target.closest('form') )
    
    fetch('sistema/atualiza_cant.php',{ method:'post',body:fd })
      .then( r=>r.text() )
      .then( data=>{
        console.log( data )
      })
      .catch( err=>console.log(err.message) )
  }
})
```

```html
<form name='form' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='id_empresa' value='qwerty1' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='text' name='id_cart' value='perc4s' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='number' name='cant' value='32' onClick='this.select();' />
</form>

<form name='form' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='id_empresa' value='frikr6' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='text' name='id_cart' value='gumbo7d' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='number' name='cant' value='54' onClick='this.select();' />
</form>

<form name='form' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='id_empresa' value='mumpy41' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='text' name='id_cart' value='pleb6s' style='display:none;' />
  <input type='number' name='cant' value='84' onClick='this.select();' />
</form>
```

Comment: I confirmed the answer as correct because it really served me. The point is that it didn't solve my problem, because it doesn't update at the moment, for example, I have the price that appears in the sequence and it doesn't update and I wouldn't like to reload the page because everything I show in the menu, and if I do a reload closes the side menu. If you can contribute with any ideas so I can update the prices, or reload the page returning to the same point with the menu open, I'd appreciate it Thanks profesor Abrosius

Comment: `" I have the price that appears in the sequence and it doesn't update"` - where? You need to use the ajax callback to perform operations using the response data. Please clarify